# update response object without converting to java object

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate, json-deserialization

Is it possible to update a field in REST response without converting to corresponding java object? I have a scenario where I have to call the GET api and update a field from true to false and make a PUT call to update it. **GET and PUT apis are not on my control as these are external apis to me**. Its pretty straight forward in javascript but not sure how would I achieve this in java. Reason I dont want to convert into java object is its a heavy object for which I have to create at least 20 classes.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can use PACTH method to update data partially.

Comment: GET and PUT are external apis. The only thing I have to do is make a GET call, update a field in GET call's response and make a PUT call with that updated response

Comment: Are you calling these external webservices from java or javascript.

Comment: Java. If you read the question carefully, I have mentioned it clearly

Answer (score 1):

If the Response from the GET API call is JSON, then follow the steps

- Convert the Response to a JSON object.
- Get the key and modify the value.
- Convert the response JSON object back to JSON string

  Now the response is updated and you can make the PUT API call. **Using JSON objects avoids the risk of converting the response to corresponding JAVA objects**.

Comment: Thanks Venkat. Liked your idea but the problem I am seeing while doing so is: converting Response object to JSONObject.  My sample code: ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class); and convert this to JSONObject as JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)response.getBody(); I am getting org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Comment: And if I change the responseType as String as ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class); 
 then I get Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@64fe75af; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@64fe75af; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: Can you please share a sample code about calling the GET and PUT external API's?

Comment: [GET]: ResponseEntity<Object> response =restTemplate.exchange(getURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);                                                   
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)response.getBody(); //this is where its failing